# Creating a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this function to create a list of lists, according to some rules i implemented, but it gives me an annoying error, i can't understand how to fix.

Here's the list it receives:

```
["3123","11254","790","86214","114125","36214"]
```

and the value is

```
num = 7
```

Here's the function:

```
create_list_of_lists :: Integral t => [t] -> t -> [t]
create_list_of_lists (x:xs) num = [x `div`z | x <- xs, z <- [1..num]]
```

When i compile it, i get no errors, but when i run it with this command:

```
create_list_of_lists ["3123","11254","790","86214","114125","36214"] 7
```

i get this errors:

[image: run_function]

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: No instance for `Integral [Char]`; No instance for `Num [Char]`.  The type `[Char]` does not have an instance for `Integral` or `Num`, which tells you that you're probably passing in the wrong type.  These error can also sometimes mean that you have the wrong constraints on your function, such as if you have `Integral` and `Fractional` (these are obviously not compatible mathematically), but these issues are more rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are passing it as list of `String` and not as list of `Integer`. This should work:

```
*Main> create_list_of_lists [3123,11254,790,86214,114125,36214] 7
[11254,5627,3751,2813,2250,1875,1607,790,395,263,197,158,131,112,86214,43107,28738,21553,17242,14369,12316,114125,57062,38041,28531,22825,19020,16303,36214,18107,12071,9053,7242,6035,5173]
```

If you want to pass it as a list of strings then perform the conversion using the `read` function. Something like this:

```
*Main> let y =  ["3123","11254","790","86214","114125","36214"] 
*Main> let x = map read y :: [Int]
*Main> x
[3123,11254,790,86214,114125,36214]
```

Or as @bheklir says you can use `readMaybe` which will convert them safely.

Comment: However, if i must pass a list of Strings, how can i do it ?

Comment: @dcarou You should convert your list of `String`s into a list of `Int`, you can do this unsafely with `read`, but I always recommend `Text.Read.readMaybe` which can fail safely, then you can use `Data.Maybe.catMaybes` to get a list of all the successful conversions to `Int`.

Comment: @dcarou Can you create a new question for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975626/struggling-with-lists-in-haskell there it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing around as a string . Please use

```
create_list_of_lists [3123,11254,790,86214,114125,36214] 7
```

Additionally you can use `read` for your intended purpose

```
let create_list_of_lists (x:xs) num = [read x `div`z | x <- xs, z <- [1..num]]
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Text-Read.html