# Struggling with lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with a list of lists in Haskell.

Here's my function:

```
create_matrix :: (Read t, Integral t) => [String] -> t -> [[t]]
create_list_of_lists (x:xs) num = [read x `div`z | z <- [1..num]] : create_list_of_lists xs num
```

When i run it like this:

```
create_list_of_lists ["1212","3232"] 3
```

i get sort off the desired output, which is

```
[[1212,606,404],[3232,1616,1077]
```

but it misses the last ']' at the end, and presents me with this error:

```
Exception: hondt.hs:39:1-81: Non-exhaustive patterns in function create_list_of_lists
```

I guess it has to do with types, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that due to Haskell's laziness GHCi is printing out the first two sub-lists as it receives them, but then runs into an error.  This error is because you haven't defined all the possible inputs for `create_list_of_lists`, namely when the first argument is empty.  You'll need

```
create_list_of_lists [] num = ???
create_list_of_lists (x:xs) num = [read x `div`z | z <- [1..num]] : create_list_of_lists xs num
```

Without the clause for `[]`, you'll end up calling `create_list_of_lists [] num`, which is currently undefined.

Comment: Thank you, i just have to cover the empty list case. So Simple afterall.

Comment: @dcarou As a followup, whenever you see "Non-exhaustive patterns in function ...", it means that you have missed a case somewhere.  If you compile your code with `ghc -Wall` (turns on all warnings), then GHC can tell you which cases you're missing, and this covers guards and case statements as well.  I use `-Wall` 100% of the time, it helps catch these small mistakes, and many other possible bugs as well.